# Refresh an image when it is clicked (play animation on click - shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a satisfaction survey. Which is pretty simple, or so I thought. It is just three smiley faces. I thought that it would be great fort he user to receive some feedback that the smiley has been clicked. While the notification message is great, I thought that it would be great that the images would play a simple animation on click. Here are the [png picture](https://ibb.co/7JR97yP) and a [test gif](https://ibb.co/rxH74Fd) fort he happy smiley. It will be enough to reproduce the issue, just save the images in the folder images.

My idea was to initially just use the png picture at start of the app and then when the image is clicked the gif replaces the png image every time it is clicked. I have tried countless ways and googled everything, but I'm stuck. 
If anyone has an idea how to tackle this issue, here is the very basic code :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),

   fluidRow(column(div(id = "happy", plotOutput("plot1")),width = 2,offset =1)
     )
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderImage({
       filename <- normalizePath(file.path('./images',  paste('happy','.png', sep='')))
       list(src = filename, width=250, height=250)
    }, deleteFile = FALSE)

  onclick(                            
    "happy", 
    { 
      #do stuff
      print("clicked on happy")
      showNotification(h4("Thanks!"), duration = 2,closeButton = FALSE, type = "message")
      })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrea's response was very helpful here. While the matter could not be done as it was intended since the .gif does not play at every click. There is another way to get a feedback at every click, which is to include [CSS animation](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to provide the visual feedback for the users. It is very simple to do so. To Andrea's code, I added the call to the CSS file with tags$head(includeCSS("./www/animate.css")) and then in the section of the code where the next image is loaded on click I added the attribute class = "animated pulse". The whole code is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(includeCSS("./www/animate.css")),
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(column(div(id = "happy", uiOutput("plot1")),width = 2,offset =1)
  )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Render a UI element instead of an image
  output$plot1 <- renderUI({
    div(id = "my_img",
        tags$img(src="0.png", height=250, width=250),
        width = 2, offset =1 )
  })

  onclick(
    "plot1", 
    { 
      print("clicked on happy")
      showNotification(h4("Thanks!"), duration = 2,closeButton = FALSE, type = "message")

      # Update UI element on click
      output$plot1 <- renderUI({
        div(id = "my_img",
            tags$img(src="0.png", class = "animated pulse", height=250, width=250),
            width=2, offset=1)
      })
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring your code a little bit (rendering a UI element instead of an image) I managed to render the gif on click. This solution is only partial as after rendering the gif the UI element doesn't go back to the previous state (`0.png`) so it will fail to render the gif on subsequent clicks.

As a general rule, it is best practice to put images in a `www/` folder.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(column(div(id = "happy", uiOutput("plot1")),width = 2,offset =1)
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  # Render a UI element instead of an image
  output$plot1 <- renderUI({
    div(id = "my_img",
    tags$img(src="0.png", height=250, width=250),
    width = 2, offset =1 )
  })

  onclick(
    "plot1", 
    { 
      print("clicked on happy")
      showNotification(h4("Thanks!"), duration = 2,closeButton = FALSE, type = "message")

      # Update UI element on click
      output$plot1 <- renderUI({
        div(id = "my_img",
            tags$img(src="happygif.gif"),
            width=2, offset=1)
      })
    }
  )

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Reading around i do believe there might be a better solution using `observeEvent` (observing click on the img tag) but it goes beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you that you took the time to provide some help regarding my issue, your answer was very useful. It looks like the .gif approach is not the way to go here, since it plays only on the first click. I ended up modifying your code a bit to be able to provide continuous visual feedback on every click with the help of CSS animation. It is explained in the edit to my question. Thanks again.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and it's a way more solid approach (will definitely turn out useful in the future). For future readers, please post it as your own answer and accept it.